# Metanalysis in R risk ratio compared to log risk ratio?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, relative-risk

I have conducted a meta-analysis with the risk ratios and standard errors that have been provided to me. I cannot use the raw data.

I was wondering if I should use the log of the risk ratio and the standard error ( the standard error already given to me). Or do I need to adjust the standard errors as I am now using the log risk ratios?

Comment: I didn't think risk ratios had a standard error, as they don't have a symmetrical sampling distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar proboem (not exactly the same, though):
SEs are the same for logRR and RR; the main difference is that the latter use the exponential of a more complex formila to calculate Conf-Int limits:

exp[RR(+/-)1.96 SE(RR) ]= RR Conf-int limits

Thus no adjustment in the se are needed.

As another confirmation: if you're using metafor you can try to use the *print()* function of the escalc used to calculate outcomes, specifing "transf = exp": you will notice tha outcomes and confidence intervals will be transformated while SEs will remain the same.

Hope this will help you